# How to test image segmentation algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, image-processing, computer-vision

What would be an ideal environment/manner to judge the effectiveness of multiple segmentation algorithms? The goal is to determine which algorithms provide the best results for pre-clinical imaging. Our group has considered a GUI in MATLAB, and have different modules for different algorithms. Various papers have conducted such algorithm analyses in clinical scenarios, but none give an indication to their environment.

Comment: "Ideal" is subjective / a matter of opinion, and subjective questions are typically not a good fit here.  What are you trying to achieve?  What approaches have you considered?  What are your goals?  What research have you done/  Please edit your question to flesh it out in considerably more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Google "image segmentation benchmark".  You will find various data sets with ground truth, such as [this one](https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/).